# Modal window is not opening in IE10(SCRIPT5009: 'UI' is undefined )

Tags: javascript, user-interface, internet-explorer, modal-dialog

I have opened a new modal window through javascript and it is working fine on firefox and chrome but not working Internet Explorer 10

> Error: SCRIPT5009: 'UI' is undefined

Code I am using:

```
UI.Modal.close();
UI.Modal.open(url,'Create New Application',{ renderAs: 'iframe',dimensions: {width:700,height:330} });
```

Comment: Are you using any library?

Comment: library means js files

Comment: Yes, it means js files

Comment: bootstrap.min.js,tooltips.js